# Create empty directories with cloud_init

Tags: cloud-init

I am trying to configure an user account using one cloud-init yaml file that include a call to [write_files](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#write-files) module, like this:

```yaml
write_files:
#passwd file for vncserver
- path: /home/ubuntu/.vnc/passwd
  owner: ubuntu:ubuntu
  permissions: '0600'
  defer: true
  encoding: b64
  content: bmtzZGN1eQo=
```

The file is created as expected, but the problem is that the parent directory is owned by root, and not by ubuntu user.

```
$ ls -la .vnc/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Dec 20 16:24 .
drwxr-x--- 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Dec 20 16:24 ..
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    8 Dec 20 16:24 passwd
```

I tried to manually create the /home/ubuntu/.vnc/ directory prior to create the passwd file to be able to set the ownership of the directory, just to find that documentation of [write_files](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#write-files) does not explain how to create (empty) directories.

I know that I could do this using `runcmd` module to insert a command like this:

```yaml
runcmd:
  - mkdir --mode 0600 --parents /home/ubuntu/.vnc
  - echo bmtzZGN1eQo | base64 -d > /home/ubuntu/.vnc/passwd
  - chmod 0600 /home/ubuntu/.vnc/passwd
```

but this seems to be too complex to do such small task.

It is possible to use write_files module to create directories or change ownership/permission of existing directories?

Comment: `write_files` does not support creating an empty directory. I am also not aware any module that can create empty directory, _see_ https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html.

Comment: Why not just write an empty hidden file?  `path: /path/to/.emtpy; content:`

Comment: Because the parent directory still will be owned by root.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a bootcmd section to to precreate the directories before the files are created. The bootcmd section runs very early, before most other cloud-init modules. Be aware that:

- Unlike runcmd, the bootcmd section runs on every boot, even after cloud-init is done. So it must not assume a clean environment. Use of `cloud-init-per once` is recommended.
- Because it runs so early, cloud-init modules like volume mounting and network initialization are not yet done. Also, user/group creation may not be done either (on first boot), so you may need to use numeric UID/GID and know in advance what the UID and GID of the user will be. For simple environments with a single boot drive that is used for everything, and a known UID/GID, this may not affect you, but it could be a problem if volumes are mounted later in cloud-init, or the UID/GID are dynamic.

```yaml
bootcmd:
 - [ cloud-init-per, once, mkdir, -m, 0755, -p, /home/ubuntu ]
 - [ cloud-init-per, once, chown, 1000:1000, /home/ubuntu ]
 - [ cloud-init-per, once, mkdir, -m, 0700, -p, /home/ubuntu/.vnc ]
 - [ cloud-init-per, once, chown, 1000:1000, /home/ubuntu/.vnc ]
write_files:
- path: /home/ubuntu/.vnc/passwd
  owner: ubuntu:ubuntu
  permissions: '0600'
  defer: true
  encoding: b64
  content: bmtzZGN1eQo=
```

This approach is probably overkill for your particular problem. Your solution of fixing the permissions in runcmd is fine, although you also need to change the owner of the created directories. It might be cleaner to write the file to a temporary location accessible only to root, then create the dir and move the file to its final location and set permissions in runcmd (after the user/group are created, if necessary).

```yaml
write_files:
- path: /root/vnc-passwd
  permissions: '0600'
  encoding: b64
  content: bmtzZGN1eQo=
runcmd:
 - [ mkdir, -m, 0700, -p, /home/ubuntu/.vnc ]
 - [ chown, ubuntu:ubuntu, /home/ubuntu/.vnc ]
 - [ rsync, -a, --chown=ubuntu:ubuntu, /root/vnc-passwd, /home/ubuntu/.vnc/passwd ]
```